# Behaviour of Python non-greedy regular expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, non-greedy

I'm using python version 3.4.1 and I don't understand the result of the following regular
expression:

```
import re
print(re.match("\[{E=(.*?),Q=(.*?)}\]","[{E=KT,Q=P1.p01},{E=KT2,Q=P2.p02}]").groups())
('KT', 'P1.p01},{E=KT2,Q=P2.p02')
```

I would expect the result to be

```
('KT', 'P1.p01')
```

but apparently the second .*? 'eats' all characters until '}]' at the end.
I would expect to stop at the first '}" character.

If I leave out the '[' and ']' characters the behavior is as I expect:

```
print(re.match("{E=(.*?),Q=(.*?)}","{E=KT,Q=P1.p01},{E=KT2,Q=P2.p02}").groups())

('KT', 'P1.p01')
```

Comment: You can see an explanation of a regex at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jO6cU0).

Answer (score 4):

The `\]` forces a square bracket to be present in the match - and there only is one at the end of the string. The regex engine has to other option to match. If you remove it or make it optional (`\]?`), it stops at the closest `}`.

Comment: Or you can add greedy `.*` between the bracket and the `}` as well.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to want is everything between `'{E='` and the next comma `','`, then everything between `'Q='` and the next closing brace `'}'`. One expression to do this would be:

```
{E=([^,]*),Q=([^}]*)}
```

Here e.g. `[^,]*` means *"as many non-comma characters as possible"*.

Example usage:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("{E=([^,]*),Q=([^}]*)}", 
               "{E=KT,Q=P1.p01},{E=KT2,Q=P2.p02}")
[('KT', 'P1.p01'), ('KT2', 'P2.p02')]
```

You can see the full explanation in [this regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fV5fB2).